# How to convert a 2D object array to a 2D string array in C#?

Tags: c#, string, object, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array of objects called 'value'. I want to convert it to a 2D string array. How do I do this?

```
object value; //This is a 2D array of objects
string prop[,]; //This is a 2D string
```

If possible I would also like to know if I can convert the object to

```
List<List<string>>
```

directly.

Comment: can you please add some code to understand the question

Comment: Please make sure that you have read "how to ask a good question". Following these guidelines will make it easier for others to answer, and the responses you get will be better and show up quicker. Details are described here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I thought the question header itself is self explanatory. I just need a function to convert 2D object to 2D string array

Comment: what is "2d object"?

Comment: 'object' is the basic class for many other classes in C#. See here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Do you have object or object[,] ?

Comment: I know what is object, but what is "2d object"? There's no such a thing in c#. Do you mean 2d array of object?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I read the value from Excel and range.Value returns a 2D object array.

Comment: so you get something like this `"(1,2)"` and want to convert that to a `prop[0][0]="1"` and `prop[0][1]="2"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
        string[,] prop; //This is a 2D string
        List<List<string>> mysteryList;

        if (value is object[,])
        {
            object[,] objArray = (object[,])value;

            // Get upper bounds for the array
            int bound0 = objArray.GetUpperBound(0);//index of last element for the given dimension
            int bound1 = objArray.GetUpperBound(1);

            prop = new string[bound0 + 1, bound1 + 1];
            mysteryList = new List<List<string>>();

            for (int i = 0; i <= bound0; i++)
            {
                var temp = new List<string>();

                for (int j = 0; j <= bound1; j++)
                {
                    prop[i, j] = objArray[i, j].ToString();//Do null check and assign 
                    temp.Add(prop[i, j]);
                }
                mysteryList.Add(temp);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question you can achieve the conversion to a 2D string array with this:

```
    List<string[]> objectValues = new List<string[]>
    {
       new[] { "1", "2", "3" },
       new[] { "A", "B", "C" },
    };

    string[,] prop = ConvertObjectListArray(objectValues );

    public T[,] ConvertObjectListArray<T>(IList<T[]> objectList)
    {
        int Length2 = objectList[0].Length;
        T[,] ret = new T[objectList.Count, Length2];
        for (int i = 0; i < objectList.Count; i++)
        {
            var array = objectList[i];
            if (array.Length != Length2)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException
                    ("All arrays must be the same length");
            }
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < Length2; i2++)
            {
                ret[i, i2] = array[i2];
            }
        }
        return ret;

    }
```