# MySql query to two dimensional array in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays, .net, multidimensional-array

I want to read data from mysql query with reader and convert it to two dimensional array. How to do it? I try with data table, but it gives me error on last line.

```
MySqlDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
DataTable Result = new DataTable();
Result.Load(Reader);
Reader.Close();
return Result.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ItemArray).ToArray();
```

"Cannot convert object[][] to string[][]".

***EDIT:*** I resolve this problem with "for" loop, but i am not sure if this is the best way to convert mysql query to two dimensional array, so i am stil looking for your help.

```
DataTable Result = new DataTable();
Result.Load(Command.ExecuteReader());

if (Result.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    object[][] Objects = Result.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ItemArray).ToArray();
    string[][] Texts = new string[Objects.Length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < Texts.Length; i++)
    {
        Texts[i] = new string[Objects[i].Length];
        for (int j = 0; j < Objects[i].Length; j++)
        {
            Texts[i][j] = Objects[i][j].ToString();
        }
    }
    return Texts;
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"ToArray()" converts to an array of type Object. You will have to cast the array to a String array. 
I hope this helps!

Comment: I try to cast with `return (string[][])Result.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ItemArray).ToArray();`, but it not work. I surround it with try catch and now i have " Unable to cast object of type System.Object[][] to type System.String[][]" error.

Comment: Try something like this:

`return Array.ConvertAll(Result.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ItemArray).ToArray(), x => x.ToString());`

Comment: "Cannot convert from string[] to string[][]." Note that i want two dimensional array.

Comment: Have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37474933/how-to-convert-a-2d-object-array-to-a-2d-string-array-in-c

Comment: Ok, i do it with "for" loop, but in some other way, thanks for help. But i am not sure if loop is the best solution (performance, etc.) to convert mysql query to two dimensional array.